# Moving Picturebox on a Grid is inaccurate because Mouse Positions are inaccurate

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

I have an Application where I put Pictureboxes on a Panel. After I successfully implemented Drag&Drop for the Pictureboxes, I wanted to add a Grid option to conviniently move the Pictureboxes on the Panel. The code I used is

```
private void PB14_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (grid)
            {
                if (MousePosition.X % 10 == 0)
                {
                    PBList[14].Location = new Point(PList[parent].PointToClient(new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)).X, PBList[14].Location.Y);
                }
                if (MousePosition.Y % 10 == 0)
                {
                    PBList[14].Location = new Point(PBList[14].Location.X, PList[parent].PointToClient(new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)).Y);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

PList is a List of Panels, PList[parent] is the parent in which the picturebox (out of a Pictureboxlist) PBList[14] is.

The Problem is that the Picturebox is not smoothely moving, sometimes it doesnt move at all. I found out that some values for the % operation are better some are worse, for example if I put

```
if (MousePosition.X % 30 == 0)
```

in the if statement, it is worse than 10.

I put the values of the if() in labels and i saw that it would sometimes skip the calculation, means the value jumped from 9 to 1, skipping the pixel where it should be 0 and the Picturebox didnt move.

Do you know any better ways of calculating the mouse coordinates for this purpose?

Comment: I already tried using e.X and e.Y but the result was even worse.

Comment: `some values for the % operation are better some are worse` Do you know what you doing in if statement? Or better explain what you would like to calculate in if statement

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you only move anything when the mouse is exactly over one of the grid points.
One way to do this is allowing an extra pixel on each side:

```
if ((MousePosition.X+1) % 30 < 3)
{
    int newX = MousePosition.X + 1 - ((MousePosition.X+1) % 30);
    PBList[14].Location = new Point(PList[parent].PointToClient(new Point(newX, MousePosition.Y)).X, PBList[14].Location.Y);
}
//Same for Y
```

Comment: Good idea I tested this and it definitely runs smoother! nice :)

Comment: The other option I was going to mention, like colin suggested, is to always process the mouse move and place next to the nearest grid point.

Comment: I use now a combination of AlexDev's and Colon Steel's Idea and the grid is working nice and smooth. Thank you!

Comment: colin ... sorry ... my mistake :/

Comment: @user2609851 btw if you liked both answers you can upvote both!

Comment: i have no reputation to do this :/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to determine the closest pixel of the grid pixels to your mouse position.

```
PBList[14].Location = new Point(PList[parent].PointToClient(new Point(MousePosition.X - (MousePosition.X % 10) + 5, MousePosition.Y - (MousePosition.Y % 10) + 5)).X);
```

Although my confusion is setting in here about the required parameters for PointToClient.

The jist of it is, recalculate the position for each mouse move regardless of whether it is directly on your 'grid by 10s', assign the location if it is different from the last (to save resources on re-painting) and find the closest 'grid by 10s' position by subracting the co-ords remainder of 10 from the co-ord

Comment: Good idea as well I will test this now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add snap-to-grid behaviour to my typical drag-and-drop implementation. The grid is based on the `Control`'s `Height` and `Width`. You can change this by replacing `control.Height` and `control.Width` with constants, if you prefer. You may also want to prevent the `Control` from being dragged off screen.

```
    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            control.Left = ((e.X + control.Left) / control.Width) * control.Width;
            control.Top = ((e.Y + control.Top) / control.Height) * control.Height;
        }
    }
```

If you want the `Control` to drag smoothly and only snap-to-grid when you release the mouse button instead:

```
    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            control.Left += e.X - offset.X;
            control.Top += e.Y - offset.Y;
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        control.Left = ((control.Left + control.Width / 2) / control.Width) * control.Width;
        control.Top = ((control.Top + control.Height / 2) / control.Height) * control.Height;
    }

    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        offset = e.Location;
    }
```